# Post JSON to streak in excel vba

Tags: json, vba, excel, api

I'm trying to update a large number of boxes on streak, and I have all these information in an excel sheet, however I realize when the request is sent, I ended up with "Sector12" on the website instead Sector12.value.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance

```
        With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "POST", "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/" & boxK & "/fields/1007", False
            .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            Sector12 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(JsonBox.Item(Index).Item("name"), ActiveSheet.Range("A:D"), 2, 0)


            .Send "{'value':Sector12}"

        End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the literal string "{'value':Sector12}" as your JSON

Should be more like this:

```
.Send "{'value':" & Sector12 & "}"
```